# How to add env variable to react

Tags: node.js

I have repeatedly kept my confidential information in the file. But I gave the name of the file. I'm looking wrong. What will I do now? I wrote the code well but it looks wrong to me

Comment: Please share more information, some code or your approach what you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

first you have to create a file named .env,
then in this file you have to put your secret key value that you don't want to share or that is harmful to share,
then you have to call dynamically the secret key name in your main file,
and most importantly you have to add thid .env or write .env to gitignore file.